# Is there a way to sort a string with OrderBy while ignoring white spaces?

Tags: c#

So, i need to sort the first line from a text file in an ascending order, it goes like this:

> 32 73 36 3 90 60 27 56 3 19 63 42 47 74 100 56 88 35 83 1 6 17 57 62 21

After it's sorted it should look like:

> 1 3 3 6 17 19 21 27 32 36 etc.

Im still pretty new at C# so i tried to code it like this:

```cs
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../text.txt");
lines[0] = String.Concat(lines[0].OrderBy(x => x));
```

The output is:

```
00001111222222
```

Is there anyway to ignore white spaces and not sort it by single numbers but by two?

`23 24 25` instead of `1 1 1 1 2 2 2`?

Comment: split by space, parse as int, order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string on spaces, then parse as ints, order, then join e.g. (without error checking):

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../text.txt");
var sorted = lines[0]
    .Split()
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
    .OrderBy(x => x);
return string.Join(" ", sorted);
```

Comment: I think I would go for `OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x))`. Shorter and faster (though it won't matter much)

Comment: `OrderBy(int.Parse)` ;)